# Why filter pipe does not work?

Tags: angular

I have the following pipe filter:

```
@Pipe({name: 'weekByRange'})
export class WeekByRangePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Week[], value: number): any {
    return items.filter(function(item: Week) {
      return ( item.group == value);
    });
  }
}
```

And I call this:

```
<md-option *ngFor="let item of weeks | weekByRange: newEducationYearModel.range" [value]="item.id">
```

`Weeks` object is:

```
[ { "id": 6012, "name": "Регулярная", "group": 6010 }, { "id": 6013, "name": "Первая неделя", "group": 6011 }, { "id": 6014, "name": "Вторая неделя", "group": 6011 } ]
```

`newEducationYearModel.range` object is: 6011

So, I dont get filtered rows in `md-select` list. Also there are not any errors.

Model is:

```
public newEducationYearModel: CreateEducationYear;
```

It is filled like as:

```
public editPeriod(item: Period) {
    this.loadWeeks();
    this.newEducationYearModel.range = 6011;
}
```

Comment: I can guess that this filter works faster than AJAX request returns main result. Because I load `weeks` by Ajax.

Comment: Can I set custom pipe as `async`?

Comment: Please add the code that shows how you get the value for `newEducationYearModel`

Comment: Okay, one minute

Comment: Done, see again

Comment: I guess it's possible to fix the code just by making this pipe impure, but this is the wrong way to handle this. You likely need to keep a promise/observable that is returned from loadWeeks and stick to it.

Comment: I can't see anything async in your code. Where do you call `editPeriod()` from? Do you get any errors?